# Free topological groups as smooth infinite-dimensional manifolds

Tags: gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds

It is known that the Graev free topological group $F(I)$ of the segment $I=[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^\infty=\lim\limits_{\longrightarrow}\mathbb R^n$. Is it possible to make an indentification of $F(I)$ and $\mathbb R^\infty$ so that the multiplication and the inversion are smooth maps (i.e. the direct limits of smooth of finite-dimensional manifolds)?

The problem was posed on 19.11.2019 by Mykhailo Zarichnyi (Lviv) on page [33](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=33) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize.** The poetry book "net.лінне" of M. Zarichnyi.